# Rare usage or Manifest error?

Tags: word-usage

Can "manifest" mean "above, over, highest" and the likes, as in the statement: "you are the manifest, there is nothing above you"?

Comment: manifest error :-)

Comment: I wonder if you confused *manifest* with *magnificent*.

Comment: No confusion. The word was translated from Arabic as Adh-Dhahir whereas magnificent would be Ar-Rayi.

Comment: In the 19th century US there was a belief system referred to as [**Manifest destiny**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifest_destiny). Not sure if this is what you have in mind, though.

Comment: *Manifest* means 'clearly visible'. In the saying "You are The Manifest, there is nothing above You", *nothing above you* is not an explanation of the term *The Manifest*: it employs the term *The Manifest* as a title of Allah (see Quran 57:3). In fact, it seems to be a witty pun on one meaning of *dhihar*, "the sense of a word which first comes to mind in a particular context" [(source)](https://umabdullah.wordpress.com/2007/04/22/meaning-of-dhahir-translated-to-literal-in-english/). So the meaning in the saying is *You are Allah, there is nothing above You*.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't want to say that it *can't* be used this way, but I think it sounds quite odd.  I would not use manifest in that way!